# Kill a process after creating not working

Tags: visual-c++

I've somehow written a program to spawn a process but unable to kill it after 2 seconds automatically( It actually does not kill):

```
void createproc() {
    //WaitForSingleObject(&processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE)

    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

    wchar_t commandline_args[] = L"\"C:\\ddnvnc\\WebServer.exe\" ";

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        commandline_args,        // Command line
        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
        0,              // No creation flags
        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
        &pi)           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
        )
    {

        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        MessageBox(NULL,
        _T("Failed"),
            _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
            NULL);
    }

    Sleep(2000);
    CloseHandle(&pi.hThread);
    TerminateProcess(&pi.hProcess,0);



    MessageBox(NULL,
        _T("KIlled"),
        _T("Windows Desktop Guided Tour"),
        NULL);


}
```

What I want is to spawn and kill the process after 2 seconds, this will be in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> CloseHandle(&pi.hThread);
> TerminateProcess(&pi.hProcess,0);
> ```

Use `pi.hThread` instead of `&pi.hThread`. Note that the order should be reversed.

You can use `WaitForSingleObject` instead of `Sleep`, and terminate the process only if it's not terminated already (for example by the user)

```
//Sleep(2000);
//TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);

if(WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 1000) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
    TerminateProcess(pi.hProcess, 0);

CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
```

Comment: Makes sense to close thread, then process, but MSFT's own example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-processes closes hProcess first. does it matter, or is MSFT documentation wrong, and if so, where is the correct order documented?

Comment: It doesn't matter. `CloseHandle` is just closing handles which are not being used. I made a separate comment about `TerminateProcess`, which should be called before `CloseHandle`. But calling `TerminateProcess`, in this way, is not recommended anyway.

Comment: Ah thank you, thought your comment was referring to thread vs process closehandle, didn't realize it was referring to terminateprocess vs closehandle.